# How to set different linespacing in different area of a line?

Tags: xetex, line-spacing

As shown in the picture, I set the first paragraph to 1.5x line spacing and the second paragraph to 2x line spacing.
[image]

It seems to me that the second paragraph has too much spacing in the formula. So, what I really want, is to set the red area to 2x line spacing and the blue area to 1.5x line spacing.
[image]

Here is my code.

```latex
\documentclass[UTF8, 12pt]{article}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.7cm, bottom=2.7cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{setspace}


\begin{document}
\begin{spacing}{1.5}
1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, $
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
    x + y - 2z - 1 = 0  \\
    x + 2y - z + 1 = 0
\end{aligned}
\right.
$ consectetuer adipiscing elit.
\end{spacing}

\vspace{20pt}

\begin{spacing}{2}
2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, $
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
    x + y - 2z - 1 = 0  \\
    x + 2y - z + 1 = 0
\end{aligned}
\right.
$ consectetuer adipiscing elit.
\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If it's only about spacing in equations, change `\jot`, e.g. `\setlength\jot{12pt}`, which affects lines in ongoing equations. BTW, while not an expert at fonts I am sure you should use either `\onehalfspacing` and `\doublespacing`, or environments `\begin{onehalfspace}....` and `\begin{doublespace}...`. If you really want numbers, the formulae is `SP/B` where B is ratio between baseline skip and font size and usually is 1.2, while SP is the spacing you want, e.g. 2/1.2 = 1.67; 1.67 should be use instead of 2 to get double-spacing in your document.

Comment: Let me have a try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nobody should be forced to use “double spacing” to begin with: it's a legacy from the time of typewriters that has little reason nowadays, when corrections are often done directly on a PDF as pop-up notes.<sup>1</sup>

By the way, the main reason for double spacing in theses was twofold: maximize the number of pages by minimizing the content of each, so if something had to be added or deleted at the last moment, only one page had to be retyped.

Anyway, here's how you can do it.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}

\geometry{a4paper, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.7cm, bottom=2.7cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\AtBeginEnvironment{aligned}{\linespread{1.5}\selectfont}


\begin{document}

\begin{spacing}{1.5}
1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, $
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
    x + y - 2z - 1 = 0  \\
    x + 2y - z + 1 = 0
\end{aligned}
\right.
$ consectetuer adipiscing elit.
\end{spacing}

\vspace{20pt}

\begin{spacing}{2}
2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, $
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
    x + y - 2z - 1 = 0  \\
    x + 2y - z + 1 = 0
\end{aligned}
\right.
$ consectetuer adipiscing elit.
\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Similar adjustments should be done for the other `amsmath` environments you use.

**Footnote**

<sup>1</sup> Maybe double spacing can be useful when submitting proofs to allow for interlinear corrections. However, in this case, the spacing issues you ask about are pretty irrelevant.

Handing in the final printed version of a thesis double spaced (and maybe one-sided, with wide margins, as still required by some antiquated regulations) is a waste of precious resources and should be proscribed.

Comment: While it's true that the original reason for double-spacing dissertations is long gone, there are still times when reading and commenting on paper is more convenient.  I object to this being stated as an absolute.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I beg to disagree, but I reworded nonetheless.

Comment: It's really useless to take a laptop on a camping trip where there will be no electric power feed available.  Some people do still read by the light of a Coleman lantern.  Maybe not many, but not zero either.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Anyway, this might be true for the proofs, where the issues presented in the question are almost irrelevant. Handing in the final printout double spaced (and maybe one-sided) is a waste of precious resources.

Comment: Now *that* I agree with totally!

Answer (score 1):

Correct with this code:

```
\begin{spacing}{2}
    2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, $
    \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
        x + y - 2z - 1 = 0  \\[-1.5ex]
        x + 2y - z + 1 = 0
    \end{aligned}
    \right.
    $ consectetuer adipiscing elit.
\end{spacing}
```